# Animation playback aggressively eats memory, doesn't give it back until program is closed and reopened

Tags: animation, memory-management

Blender is smooth as butter when I first open my file. I can work and move and edit etc with no lag. But after a few paybacks of my animation it will become more and more laggy. Taking a look at the task manager, I notice that during animation playback (a short 3-4 second looped anim) the memory usage will slowly climb higher and higher, resulting in an unworkable environment after a few paybacks and blender does not give that eaten memory back until I save and fully close and reopen the program.

Comment: Is it an image sequence you've imported?  Or what type of animation, is there any physics system being used?

Comment: Two active rigid bodies, and a few passive. Small repeating marble sequence. Some shaders, keyframes, and an hdri. Nothing fancy, no image sequence.